# python pytest-coverage: test that module defintions are actually called in the tests

Tags: python, pytest, pytest-cov

I have an issue with some ctypes code that I have, where pytest-coverage is overinflating my "true" test coverage.

Here is what the module looks like (using a dummy example):

```
# mymod.py
add = clib.add
add.arg_types = [c_int, c_int]
add.res_type = c_int
```

The problem is, when I run `pyest_coverage`, my code coverage shows at 100%, even if the *python* `add` is never called in my unit tests. Stated otherwise, if I do NOT do

```
#tests/test_mymod.py
assert mymod.add(1,2) == 3
```

I want my coverage to reflect that, meaning I want to reflect that `add` "wasn't really tested".

**OPTIONS**

My module cannot afford to take any performance hit. One thing I've thought of is to do either this:

```
def add(a, b):
    # probably really bad performance wise if called many times!!!
    _add = clib.add
    _add.arg_types = [c_int, c_int]
    _add.res_type = c_int
    return _add(a,b)
```

or

```
_add = clib.add
_add.arg_types = [c_int, c_int]
_add.res_type = c_int
def add(a, b):
    # questionable performance!!
    return _add(a,b)
```

But I fear that both of these re-organizations, for the purpose of testing, will impact the performance of the code

Any ideas how I can trick pytest or pytest-coverage into not counting `add` as covered unless some test function actually calls `add`??